# Gentoo: changing the size of a /boot partition at the beginning of a disk

Tags: boot, partition, gentoo

I'm running a box under Gentoo. Said box is a server (no GUI, only SSH).

Since I used genkernel to generate my kernel, I've seen that it creates several images (System.map, initramfs, kernel) that takes some place:

```
$ du -ahd1|sort -k1h
0       ./boot
0       ./.keep
12K     ./lost+found
1.4M    ./memtest86plus
2.4M    ./System.map-genkernel-x86_64-4.9.34-gentoo
2.7M    ./System.map-genkernel-x86_64-4.12.5-gentoo
3.7M    ./kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.9.34-gentoo
4.2M    ./initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.9.34-gentoo
8.1M    ./grub
8.3M    ./kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.12.5-gentoo
31M
```

Indeed, my /boot partition is only 32M large and I'd like to change its size to some size that better accommodate this (like 256M).

My `/dev/sda` is as follow; for reference, it is an Intel SSD (although it is an old model).

```
$ lsblk /dev/sda
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 37.3G  0 disk
├─sda2   8:2    0 37.2G  0 part /
└─sda1   8:1    0   32M  0 part /boot
```

I know I can grow a partition on some condition (end of disk, etc) and shrink it. I also know it is risky and I'm not enough confident to do it without using a good GUI.

Can I do that:

- shrink `/dev/sda2` to get some space
- create and mount `/dev/sd3` as `/new_boot`
- copy whole `/boot` to `/new_boot` (either threw a simple copy, either threw dd ?)
- swap `/boot` and `/new_boot`
- drop `/dev/sda1` and resize `/dev/sda2`

Or is there a better solution ? (I have physical access to the server)

Comment: Is a separate `/boot` partition really necessary? Is your root FS encrypted, on LVM or something like this?

Comment: Nothing complicated like that. The /boot was separated because It was like that in the gentoo manual when I installed it. -> https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Disks#Introduction_to_block_devices I had the "good" idea to use 32M.

Comment: You don't usually need the System.map files. Actually, they can pose a security risk if they're globally readable as they present an attacker the kernel memory layout.

Comment: @L29Ah On my Linux Mint `/boot/vmlinuz*` (i.e. the kernel) and `/boot/System.map*` permissions are 700. Strangely, on Debian, they are readable by everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use your root partition to store the content of `/boot`:

- `mount --move /boot /elsewhere` or `umount /boot` it and `mount` it on `/elsewhere`
- copy the content of `/elsewhere` into the now (probably) empty `/boot` while preserving the rights and owners of everything (`cp -a /elsewhere/. /boot`)
- `umount /elsewhere`
- remove `/boot` from `/etc/fstab`
- update grub (`grub-install` probably, or your Gentoo wrapper if any)
- reboot

Ensure that everything is fine and that you are not using anything from your old `/boot` partition before emptying it or recycling it (personnally I would not take any risk for 32M)

Comment: You spoke about  security risks, but the /boot partition is only mounted by the root whenever is needed (eg: kernel upgrade). Don't I risk the same problem if I let my /boot folder in the / partition ?

Comment: I didn't mention anything about security risks. The `/boot` directory rights, as well as the rights and owner of its content, must be preserved, that's all what matters. I'm going to add something about this in the answer.

Comment: I've seen. In fact that was L29Ah who mentioned the security risk.

Comment: Before I try that tonight: does grub needs to be the first partition ? If I can move /boot elsewhere, then I can probably create a partition at end of /dev/sda and keep the "don't mount /boot" idiom ?

Comment: @NoDataFound Personally I put grub at the start of the disk, when not using UEFI. Of course, since `/boot` is going to be eventually removed, grub should not be put on that partition. Apart from that, as said in my answer, you should not do anything on /boot unless you are sure that everything works without it.